# What exactly triggers the JS garbage collector?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, v8

I have a JS function that creates a large number of objects and then stops using them. I noticed that Chrome's Minor GC was taking up a significant fraction of this function's execution time, and it was causing user-noticeable delays. (Usually at least 30%, at times upwards of 75%.)

I tried retaining references to all of those objects so that they couldn't be collected. This caused the garbage collector to run much more frequently, but no out-of-memory exception was thrown, so clearly the original garbage collection was not strictly necessary in order to keep the tab running.

I tried changing the function to reuse all of its old objects rather than abandon them and create new ones, but this didn't help; the GC was still taking up just as much time as it was before.

This function needs to perform heavy computation for ~1 second in response to user input, then it's done and the browser will idle while the user reads the returned data. So I'd prefer if this unnecessary garbage collection waited until that idle time, and my experiment with refusing to release the object references shows that Chrome has enough memory to run the entire function with no garbage collection in the middle. But I can't seem to figure out what's triggering it or how to avoid it.

Looking around on the internet, I could find nothing that explains how the GC chooses when to run. Not even the [v8 dev blog](https://v8.dev/blog/tags/memory) explains it in any more detail than "it uses heuristics".

Of course I'm aware that the details will differ from browser to browser, but I'm sure there's some general concept that I could use to make it less likely to trigger right at the worst possible time like it's consistently doing now.

Comment: The details will also differ from version to version of the same browser. The specification alone intentionally gives very high amount of leeway here, from mostly deterministic reference-counting up to not implementing any garbage collection at all, and GC algorithms differ wildly. If GC pauses are that bad, try porting your algorithm to a WebAssembly runtime instead. There have been proposals to add GC hints to the language (e.g. <https://es.discourse.group/t//703/>), but nothing gained much traction.

Answer (score 4):

(V8 developer here.)

"The GC" is a complex system performing several different activities driven by a complex set of adaptive heuristics (which I don't know in detail, I only know that they're complicated enough and the details change often enough that it probably wouldn't make much sense to even try to describe them here). There isn't a simple answer to "what exactly triggers it?"; one thing that's certain is that allocations play a crucial role in triggering it, because without allocations, there are no allocated objects to clean up.

For the Minor GC specifically, it's much simpler: it runs when it needs to. V8 has a "generational" heap layout: a fairly small "new space" a.k.a. "young generation", where most objects are initially allocated, and a much larger "old space", into which objects are promoted if they live long enough. When you allocate, new-space fills up until at some point an allocation fails and a minor GC cycle is triggered. There is no alternative at that point, because new-space is full: for the allocation to succeed in a second attempt, some room has to be made first. The only way for you to avoid this is to not allocate. By artificially holding on to your objects, you're causing them to get promoted to the old generation instead of being freed; it is not surprising that that isn't any faster.

> no out-of-memory exception was thrown, so clearly the original garbage collection was not strictly necessary

As explained above, when new-space is full, then a minor GC *is* necessary. If enough free memory is available, then a *major* GC isn't necessary.

I'm sorry that this answer doesn't provide any actionable tips how to solve your problem. What you are describing is very unusual. The Minor GC is usually very fast. And avoiding allocations definitely should avoid GC runs (major or minor).
Maybe your code is doing something that causes "hidden" allocations under the hood. Perhaps if you shared some representative sample code to investigate, I might be able to say something more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My code is allocating a very large amount of memory very quickly- hundreds or even thousands of MB- so I'm not surprised that the GC wasn't designed to handle that edge case very well. Would it help if I created all those objects in advance, giving them time to be promoted to the old space before the computationally-intensive function is called, and then simply reused those existing objects within that function?

Comment: @IsaacKing Yes, reusing objects avoids allocations and hence GC activity. Waiting shouldn't even be necessary. FWIW, that is independent of GC implementation details, or even whether there's a GC at all: even in languages with manual memory management such as C/C++/Rust, reusing objects is faster than repeatedly allocating and freeing them.

Comment: Hmm, I think there's been a miscommunication somewhere. I already tried reusing objects rather than creating new ones, as I described in the original question. That didn't work, and I thought your answer had been saying that the reason it wasn't working is because those reused objects were being moved from new space to old space, so the GC still needed to run.

Comment: @IsaacKing IIUC you tried two things: (1) artificially keeping everything alive to demonstrate that enough memory is available -> more GC runs, no perf improvements. Makes sense. (2) reusing objects, where you also saw no improvements. That doesn't make sense. My best guess is that whatever you did didn't actually avoid allocations, but as long as you don't share code to investigate/analyze, guessing is all I can do. If you actually avoid allocations (e.g. by reusing an object pool, and avoiding operations that cause allocations under the hood), then that _will_ avoid GC, guaranteed.